# Timeout Exception for huge data with Linq Query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

My Linq query working only for few data in development db but same query is giving timeout exception in production db .In production db there are many data. i don't want to increase the command time rather i want a optimized query. can any one help me to optimize this query ?

```
var poStatus = (from s in ThisYearDataOnly
                                    join st in status on s.StatusID equals st

                                    group s by s.MRIPatientOrderId
                                        into x
                                    select
                                        new
                                        {
                                            MRIPatientOrderId = x,
                                            StatusId = x.OrderByDescending(c => c.ID).FirstOrDefault().StatusID
                                        }).ToList();
```

To understand the data providing previous queries :

```
sharedmsdbEntity sdb = new sharedmsdbEntity();
                using (MRIdbEntity db = new MRIdbEntity())
                {
                    string type = Request.QueryString["type"];
                    int typeID = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["typeID"]);


                    List<string> statusList = new List<string>() { "Complete" };
                    var completeStatusId = (from s in sdb.smsStatus
                                            where s.IsMRI && s.Status == MRIStatusEnum.Complete.ToString()
                                            select s.ID).FirstOrDefault();



                    var status = (from s in sdb.smsStatus select s.ID).ToList();

                    var PoOrdersYearly = (from po in db.smsMRIPatientOrders
                                          where
                                         ((po.ExamDateIn.HasValue && (po.ExamDateIn.Value.Year == DateTime.Now.Year)) || (!po.ExamDateIn.HasValue && po.ExamDateIn.HasValue && (po.ExamDateIn.Value.Year == DateTime.Now.Year))) 
                                          select po);

                    var ThisYearDataOnly = (from s in db.smsMRIPatientOrderStatus join po in PoOrdersYearly on s.MRIPatientOrderId equals po.ID select s );
```

Comment: It would be nice if you provided some data, say as a list. The join there seems to be unnecessary to me. Wouldn't it be just : from s in ThisYearDataOnly where status.Any( st => st == s.StatusID) ...? It creates an "exist" query rather than a join. (A join is seldom needed in Linq).

Comment: @CetinBasoz please check updated question if it helps.

Comment: Please do something about indents and horizontal scrolling.

Comment: I don't see any sample data for db.smsMRIPatientOrderStatus or db.smsMRIPatientOrders. The query is more complex now.

Comment: BTW, you can simplify that PoOrdersYearly: 
  var PoOrdersYearly = (from po in db.smsMRIPatientOrders
         where
        po.ExamDateIn.HasValue && (po.ExamDateIn.Value.Year == DateTime.Now.Year)
         select po);